A movie where a Solid Snake-esque character from a game comes to life?
So way back in elementary school (pre 2009), I remember us watching this movie where a guy who looks like Snake Plissken (or Solid Snake with long hair) helps these kids, or something, who have this game where things that are happening in it are happening in real life (the only scene I remember is where they're in some building, and a kid looks down at this game, which is a sides-croller I think, and sees some Ninjas. Solid Snake Plissken then gets a gun and goes out to go pummel some baddies.
And that's all I remember. It's been a long time, and all searches have turned up nothing. I don't even know if I had all the details right, but it's driving me absolutely nuts. I remember the Ninjas and a dude with black hair and an eyepatch for sure, but otherwise I have no clue.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

That is literally all i remember. It was in color (it features video games; the odds of that in a greyscale movie are quite slim) and me being in elementary school had nothing to do with the movie itself. It was a sort of reasoning for why i remember basically nothing about it. What i put in the question is what i remember. I just thought hey worth a shot to put it on here

Yes i see now. sorry, I'm not the sharpest crayon in the box sometimes. K. So the latest year I'd say is 2009 (yes, I know). I'm trying to think of other things to help identify it, but the list is very small... well, I guess if it helps I'm fairly sure it's one of those movies not quite bad enough for B-list, but still considered pretty bad (considering it's not like Jumanji or Dredd, where they have bad reviews but people seem to like them. Nobody seems to have a clue what this one is). My first thought was Escape from New York, but aside from the main character, it is completely incongruous

Surf Ninjas? There's a kid who sees the story unravel as a video game...I think there's a snake plisken like person in it.
This is basically the story of 2 brothers growing up in LA (where they surf a lot), learn that they are members of a royal family from Patusan (made up island). They were taken away when they were babies because an evil dictator took over the island. 
When they are "grown up", a warrior from Patusan comes and takes them back to their home island to reclaim the throne. This guy is the Snake Plisskin type guy. The older brother learns he has latent warrior abilities which are awakened (can fight really well), and the younger one can see/control (to some extent) what is happening or will happen via a Sega Game Gear. Then there's Rob Schneider too.
Here's a YouTube clip which has a little tasting of the things in the movie.

Hm... that looks like it... I'll have to watch it and see though. That's the closest thing to it if nothing else. 5/10 stars? I expected about as much lol.

I watched it a lot when I was a kid, so in my mind it is a 10/10! I'm scared to watch it again for fear it'd be terrible though

Thats how i am with several movies... namely Atlantis: the Lost Empire. Treasure Planet though I've seen and still quite like it. Both have pretty bad reviews, but everyone who i know who's seen them seems to like em so idk. Taste i guess

FYI, the reason I suspect this answer is attracting downvotes is because it's so short and has no supporting evidence (despite it sounding like it's probably correct.)  If you could improve the answer with some links and maybe even a screen shot of "Solid Snake Plisskin" the voting would probably turn around for you.

I fixed it up, hopefully it turns the votes around a little :/
